# valign attribute in style classes

Tags: css

When we define a style class like the below in a CSS file, it is getting rendered in IE, but FF shows empty classes. vertical-align attribute works fine in both browsers. Why do we see this behaviour?

```
.text {
   valign: middle;
}
```

Comment: `valign` is not a valid CSS attribute. If a browser interprets it anyway, it's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `valign` isn't valid CSS, while `vertical-align` is. And IE is known to ignore the rules. What more?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but why it is getting rendered in IE, does not do any validation?

Comment: Like I said, IE is known to ignore the rules. Why does it ignore the rules? Ask Microsoft.

Comment: My plan is to remove that style class from my css. Just wanted to make sure that it doesn't have any impact. Thanks a lot for you information. :)